# Is it possible to make a parameter optional in a function call without duplicating the code

Tags: php

This problem seemed obvious at first to me but I've been struggling for a while and I can't find any useful information on internet/stack overflow regarding this.

I have a function that looks like this :

```php
myfunction(string $parameter, array $optionalParameter = []) {
}
```

and in my call, something like that :

```php
myfunction('text', BOOL ?? $array);
```

The problem is that, from what I understand, passing `null` as the second argument isn't the same as having no second argument, so `$optionalParameter` isn't initialized (I use phpstan and it tells me that null is incompatible with array).

The only solution I can envision would be to duplicate the function call, but it's really not a good idea considering my actual function has way more than 2 parameters.

TLDR; I'm looking for a way to turn the return type of `BOOL ?? $array` from `array|null` to `array|(nothing)` if that makes sense

Comment: A default value is only used if no argument was given for the parameter. If you want to pass `null` for your second parameter, use `?array` or `array|null` instead of `array`. Then, in the first lines of your function, use something like `$optionalParameter = (optionalParameter === null ? [] : optionalParameter)`.

Comment: that's exactly what I was doing, but a colleague told me that I could reduce this part. If you see no other solution, I guess it's impossible

Comment: _"but a colleague told me that I could reduce this part"_ - Reduce what exactly? All you need to do is add a `?` in front of the `array $optionalParameter` in the function argument and then add one single line in the top of the function: `$optionalParameter = $optionalParameter ?? [];`. That would allow you to pass in an array, null or don't pass anything in. Not sure how to make it easier than that? If that's not what you're asking, then you need to update the question with some real examples

Comment: Since you're using PHP 8.1 you could use named arguments, although it's essentially the same issue. Null still counts as an argument. I don't see how it could be done otherwise (maybe by passing an empty array instead of null for the second parameter, it's not clear in your question if that is an option).

Comment: @M.Eriksson the idea was to remove the possibility of having "null".
I did what Noah Boegli suggested, which is probably the closest solution to what I was aiming for. Thanks for the help

Comment: _"the idea was to remove the possibility of having "null""_ - But the examples you've posted doesn't allow you to pass `null`, so now I'm more confused